# Wavelength of a particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, velocity, wave-particle-duality, wavelength

As we know wavelength of a particle is equal to (Planck's constant / momentum), so here momentum $= mv$ where $m$ is a mass of an object and $v$ is the velocity of an object. 
What will happen when velocity tends to zero? 
Wavelength of a particle can be observable?
Here velocity tends to zero not exactly equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the wavelength tends to infinity as the velocity tends to zero. Regarding observability, observing very long wavelengths is as hard as observing very low velocities, but neither is impossible in principle.

Comment: G Smith let's throw a ball when ball reaches its velocity to zero so it is possible to get low velocity of an object ?

Comment: Yes, objects can have low velocity. And they can have zero velocity. Why would you think otherwise?

Comment: this question is different because in other question he said velocity is zero but de Broglie already given an assumption that you can only use this formula when the velocity is not zero . In my question velocity tends to zero not equal to zero